# Development in Cygwin C++

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cygwin

For a few years I was writing programs in Visual Studio for Windows and with GCC (Code Blocks) for Linux. Most of my libs compiled seamlessly as they worked both in Windows and Linux. However at the moment I am a bit confused, as I have to create an app using Cygwin. I don't really understand if I am still in UNIX/Linux environment, just running app on Windows by some "emulation", or I am rather on Windows just having access to some Linux/Unix functionality. From what I understood from the FAQ's and documentation it looks like I just should behave like in Linux environment.
All explanations I found in internet usually are very general and don't explain the detailed differences from programmers viewpoint.

**Short question**: Can I just write programs like I did for Linux without any major changes when using Cygwin?

Comment: it would depend on whether you're using unix-specific pthreads, signals, fork, certain devices, etc.

Comment: You should really clarify this question a bit. Is Cygwin a specified requirement, or could you go with MinGW, for example? Are you writing cross-platform code or is it enough if it just runs on Windows? Or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Maybe.**

A lot of code written for Linux will compile in Cygwin with very few problems, which can mainly be fixed by messing with preprocessor definitions.

However, any code written for linux which:

- Uses a Linux driver
- Directly accesses the kernel
- Relies on any code which does either of these two things (and doesn't have a Windows counterpart)

will quite definitely not work, regardless of how much you modify the code.

Much as it tries to, Cygwin cannot fully emulate (*yes it is an emulator, of sorts*) everything a POSIX system can normally do.  Cygwin is **not** windows, just a conversion layer from its own machine language.

For more information, read [cygwin's wikia](http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/Intro_to_Cygwin)

Comment: What do you mean about "its own machine language"? Cygwin apps are normal Windows apps which just depend on cygwin DLLs and files, and can use other Windows DLLs as usual. Normal WIN32 API is available like for any apps.

Comment: Please note that the wikia page is NOT an officially endorsed site of the Cygwin project.  Official documentation is on cygwin.com.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I just write programs like I did for Linux without any major
>   changes when using Cygwin?

The platforms are not identical, so you can not realistically expect to write the program in Linux, and then *POOF* expect it to build and work under Cygwin. But if you don't use things not available under Windows, then you won't need *major* changes. And you *can* write non-trivial programs, which will build and work on both, perhaps needing a few `#ifdefs` in places.

From your question I take it you want to work on Linux, but write programs for running under Cygwin. In that case you must also build and test it in the Cygwin environment all the time, so:

- Use version control, commit often. I recommend a DVCS like *git* or *mercurial* which have separate *commit* and *push*, it will allow you to do commits more freely.
- Whenever you commit/push, do checkout/pull and build on the Cygwin host. You can do this manually or automatically (by simple custom script polling the version control, or by Jenkins or something).
- When ever your code stops building or working under Cygwin, fix it before continuing with new code.

---

If Cygwin is not absolute requirement, then I would look into using Qt SDK. It can be used for non-Qt projects too, the MinGW toolchain on Windows is very similar to *gcc* on Linux. And if you're willing to use Qt, then it has all sorts of platform-independent features for things you might want to do, such as discover locations of standard directories for saving files, use threads, print things, have GUI...